# Determine whether the set $W$ is a subspace in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine whether the set $W=\{(2a-2,3b,2a-3b)\}$ is a subspace in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Describe the set.

I have tried putting the set into matrix form but don't know which is correct. I also know that it needs to be closed under addition and multiplication but can't figure out how to show that.

Comment: The title asks about "subset" (not subspace); the answer to *that* question is yes.

Comment: Oops!  I totally missed that.  It *is* a subset.  It is *not* a subspace.

Comment: @Pavlo: Please do not alter the text of a question so dramatically after it has already received an answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

One of the requirements for $W$ to be a subspace is that $\langle 0, 0, 0 \rangle \in W$.  Is this the case?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** It's not a subspace. Can you think of a vector that must be in ANY subspace? This special vector is not in $W$.

Comment: Yes, isnt the zero vector supposed to be in the subspace?

Comment: Correct. Now if $(0,0,0) \in W$, then this would imply that:
$$
\begin{cases}
2a - 2 = 0 \\
3b = 0 \\
2a - 3b = 0
\end{cases}
\implies
\begin{cases}
a = 1\\
b = 0 \\
2a = 3b
\end{cases}
$$
Thus, we have that $2(1) = 3(0)$, a contradiction. So $(0,0,0) \notin W$ so that $W$ is not a subspace.

Comment: Note that any vector in $W$ has the form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2a - 2 \\ 3b \\ 2a - 3b
\end{bmatrix}
=
a\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\ 0 \\ 2
\end{bmatrix}
+b \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 3 \\ -3
\end{bmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix}
-2 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Hence, it follows that $W$ represents a plane that has been translated by $2$ units in the negative $x$ direction.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Ignoring the $(-2, 0, 0)$, observe that the two vectors $(2,0,2)$ and $(0,3,-3)$ are linearly independent and thus serve as a basis of dimension $2$ for the corresponding subspace of $W$. And yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** There is only one way to prove that a set $W$ is closed under multiplication:

1. Take an element $x\in W$ and a scalar $\alpha\in \mathbb R$
2. Prove that $\alpha\cdot x$ is an element of $W$.

Answer (score 0):

It is an affine subspace $W=\{(-2,0,0)+a[2,0,2]+b[0,3,-3]:a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$.